# How do you inject a view dependency into Presenter (MVP) in ASP.NET Web Forms using Simple Injector or Microsoft.Extensions.Dependency?

Tags: asp.net, dependency-injection, webforms, simple-injector

The following example shows a scenario where I'm trying to implement a DI container.  In this case, I'm trying to use Simple Injector or Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection DI Container.  I've seen code examples that start hitting around the target, such as [here](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resolving-unregistered-concrete-types-is-disallowed-by-default.html?highlight=.net%20web%20forms#so-what-do-you-need-to-do), but no bullseye as of yet.

Below is a general code sample that I would like to modify to use one of the aforementioned DI containers (Used Simple Injector for example). I could move the view out of the presenter constructor and set it as a property.  However, I was hoping for a more eloquent solution also it is a dependency that needs to be injected.

I know .NET 4.7.2 has increased DI support functionality but the biggest benefit seems to be allowing dependencies to be easily injected into pages/user controls.  For MVP architecture I need the concrete class of the page tied to its view interface so the DI container can resolve and pass into the presenter, as the presenter depends on the view.  I've not seen an example of this implemented well other than Unity using its DependencyOverride, which can pass the concrete class at runtime.

```
public partial class UserLoginView : IUserLoginView
{    
    private UserLoginPresenter _userLoginPresenter;

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {    
         //This is my problem:
         //An error will be thrown "...contains the parameter with name 
         //'view' and type IUserLoginView, but IUserLoginView is not 
         //registered..."    
         _userLoginPresenter = SimpleInjectorDependencyInjector
            .GetInstance<IDeveloperTestStatusPresenter>();
    }
}

public class UserLoginPresenter : IUserLoginPresenter
{
    private readonly IUserLoginView view;
    private readonly IUserService _userService;

    public UserLoginPresenter(IUserLoginView userLoginView,
        IUserService userService)
    {
        this.view = userLoginView;
        this._userService = userService;
    }


public static class SimpleInjectorDependencyInjector
{
    private static readonly Container container = new Container();

    public static T GetInstance<T>() where T : class
    {
        return container.GetInstance<T>();
    }

    //Assume this is called from App on start
    public static void RegisterClasses()
    {           
        container
            .Register<IUserLoginPresenter, UserLoginPresenter>();
        container
            .Register<IUserService, UserService>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish what I was looking for using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection Container.

In my MSDependencyInjector wrapper class, I used the ActivatorUtilities extension.

```
public static T GetService<T, I>(I interfaceInstance)
{
    return ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<T>(container, interfaceInstance);
}
```

Implemented in my page's partial class I wrote:

```
 _userLoginPresenter = MSDependencyInjector.GetService<UserLoginPresenter,
                IUserLoginView>(this);
```

A Caveat: The 'T' parameter of createInstance wants the concrete class type not the interface.  This caused hours of frustration, prompting the creation of this question in the first place.  MS documentation isn't the greatest but I definitely misread.

I'm not sure how to implement something as straightforward in Simple Injector and would be interested in knowing.  Based on my reading I not sure if my solution isn't something like a service locator, which depending on which camp you are from should be avoided.  However, if the implementation of this can be contained for just solving the need for this MVP paradigm then it is my hope all will be well.